# why is asking about plugins or methods in wp-admin to edit .htaccess off-topic?

Tags: support

I just posted this question:

[Edit or Remove Plugin .htaccess Using The Admin Panel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58183/how-to-remove-malware-htaccess-redirects-without-access-to-file-system#comment75061_58183)

It was quickly closed as off-topic because "recovering from hacks" is listed in the FAQ as something that shouldn't be posted here. However, that prohibition is listed under the sub-heading "[do not post things] that require professional hands-on involvement".

If recovering from this hack required professional hands-on involvement, I certainly would have avoided asking it, and instead sought professional hands-on involvement. However, I really don't see how this is a case where professional hands-on involvement is required. I'm just looking for a way to edit the .htaccess file. What if I had re-phrased the question, just asking for this without mentioning that it was for the purpose was to recover from a hack? That seems like the same question to me, except with less back story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a <s>mistake</s> case of different interpretations. I reopened the question already before you asked this question here. :)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm just looking for a way to edit the .htaccess file. What if I had re-phrased the question, just asking for this without mentioning that it was for the purpose was to recover from a hack?

In that case, your question would *still* be off topic.  `.htaccess` is not WordPress-specific, and editing it using raw PHP on your server is not WordPress-specific either.

Comment: Creating or deleting files per plugin is on topic in my opinion. We should find a consensus.

Comment: If you want to revisit the original question and rewrite it to reflect adding/removing files via a plugin I would agree. But as it stands now, the question is not on topic for this site.

Comment: Okay, I’ll do that.

Comment: Ok, I also edited the questions on top of the edits @toscho made to hopefully make the question stand more on-topic.

Comment: Fantastic edits. Now it is, indeed, on-topic :-)

Comment: Even as edited, I still question whether it is on-topic. It also appears to be too localized.

Comment: The only reason it gets around the recovering-from-hacks question restriction is the narrow tailoring to using a Plugin to modify `.htaccess` rather than using direct file access. (*Tried to edit my original comment, but I let more than 5 minutes pass.*)